# Poetry: Failed to unlock the collection

Tags: python, python-poetry

On a fresh poetry install, I get the following error trying to install anything:

```
(base) ➜  celeba poetry add numpy       
Failed to unlock the collection!
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems to be something to do with "keyring"? Maybe try [this suggestion](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1917#issuecomment-1235998997) from python-poetry issues

Answer (score 75):

There is an extensive discussion and various workarounds suggested in poetry issue [#1719](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1917). Probably the fastest way to make this work is to run the following before you run poetry:

```bash
export PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
```

Comment: This problem is a real black-eye for the reputation of poetry.  It's a great tool, but the fact that the maintainers simply will not fix this after years of complaints points to some real cultural problems within their team.

Answer (score 2):

If you are remotely accessing your work environment via SSH, add this function to your `.bashrc` file and run it from the remote terminal:

```
# Linux unlock gnome keyring
function unlock-keyring ()
{
    read -rsp "Password: " pass
    export $(echo -n "$pass" | gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --unlock)
    unset pass
}
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602313/unlock-gnome-keyring-daemon-from-command-line